# Gson throwing EXPECTED_ARRAY but found String Exception

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am using gson with retrofit to parse json response but I am getting the above mention exception.
I have tried searching on net and figuring it out myself but haven't got any success till now

Here is my json response:

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "message": "",
    "data": [{
        "Id": "56B5D1408B8D9",
        "Name": "John",
        "Age":"28",
        "place": "Central City"
    }]
}

my Pojo Class

public class Datum {

@SerializedName("Id")
@Expose
private String Id;
@SerializedName("Name")
@Expose
private String Name;
@SerializedName("Age")
@Expose
private String Age;
@SerializedName("place")
@Expose
private String place;

/**
* 
* @return
* The Id
*/
public String getId() {
return Id;
}

/**
* 
* @param Id
* The Id
*/
public void setId(String Id) {
this.Id = Id;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The Name
*/
public String getName() {
return Name;
}

/**
* 
* @param Name
* The Name
*/
public void setName(String Name) {
this.Name = Name;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The Age
*/
public String getAge() {
return Age;
}

/**
* 
* @param Age
* The Age
*/
public void setAge(String Age) {
this.Age = Age;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The place
*/
public String getPlace() {
return place;
}

/**
* 
* @param place
* The place
*/
public void setPlace(String place) {
this.place = place;
}

}
```

Parent Class
   package com.example;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class UserModel {

@SerializedName("success")
@Expose
private String success;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<Datum> data = new ArrayList<Datum>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The success
*/
public String getSuccess() {
return success;
}

/**
* 
* @param success
* The success
*/
public void setSuccess(String success) {
this.success = success;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The message
*/
public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

/**
* 
* @param message
* The message
*/
public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The data
*/
public List<Datum> getData() {
return data;
}

/**
* 
* @param data
* The data
*/
public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

Here is my code to parse it

private void getUserDetail(){

```
    Call<UserModel> userModelCall = Util.getEndPointService().fetchUser(sessionId, startNo);
    userModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<UserModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<UserModel> response) {
            int resCode = response.code();
            Log.i(TAG_DEBUG, "response code is " + resCode);
            if (resCode == 200) {
                UserModel userModel = response.body();
                Log.i(TAG_DEBUG, userModel.getSuccess());

                if (userModel.getSuccess().equals(StringConstants.TRUE)) {
                    retrieveDownloadedProfile(userModel);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            CLog.e(TAG_DEBUG, "Exception in getUserDetail " + t);
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please show where are you parsing the JSON? Some code will help..

Comment: I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Gson will start working from the root, you'll need a parent that matches your response like:

```
class MyResponse {
    public List<Datum> data;
}
```

Your Datum class looks like it matches the items inside the `data` array in the response

Comment: Quick question, is the class you've called Example your UserModel class?